# Azure cloud launched machine is not showing in the protectable items

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

We are trying to find our newly launched VM instance in AZURE Cloud in protectable items. However the instance is not appearing in the list. We have used azure instance/VM creation web UI to create the VM.

What could be the reason that the instance is not showing up in the protectable items? 
We do not have any active/configured backup policy for the instance yet.

Comment: Where in the portal are you looking? I am not finding anything regarding protectable items.

Answer (score 0):

For the VM to appear in protectable items list, it should belong to same region as vault and not configured for backup yet. Given that you discarded it is not the case of the latter, can you check if VM and vault are in same region?

Otherwise, an easy option is to go to VM blade and click on "Backup" part of Operations section of the left hand side menu of VM blade.